# Is it possible to enroll a non-play-certified device into the Android management API?

Tags: android-management-api

I am working with a kiosk-style device that isn't currently Play certified, and therefore has neither play services nor play store. Is it possible to enroll this with Android Management API (and as such the stock device policy controller)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Self answered. The answer is no. Android Management DPC does *NOT* work without GMS support packages.